# im upload me new script to hosting but the website not working main error ERR_too_many_redirects

Tags: php, web, hosting, htdocs

the .htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine off

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

what is the issue?

Comment: Please write undestadable question title

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the rules?

Comment: the website not open you can check main page [link](https://moe-ae.waayn.com/file)

Comment: and the admin page not open also [link](https://moe-ae.waayn.com/file/admin)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure if this is what you want to do, but try with this:

```
RewriteEngine Off
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: im trying  but not working you can check please  website main page [a link](https://www.moe-ae.waayn.com/file/)
and  admin page [a link](https://www.moe-ae.waayn.com/file/admin)

Comment: Did you try with .htaccess I sent you? I mean, exactly with that.